# Is the use of regex here POSIX compliant and is the code used appropriate for the problem described?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, posix, emoji

Following from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900817/check-whether-string-contains-emoji-in-posix-if-statement), please see below a fuller form of my question.

### Code use case

The current code is a [module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/User-contributed-modules) for use in [polybar](https://github.com/polybar/polybar), a customisable status bar. As per the first link, polybar is drawn using a configuration file and each bar that is called (by, for instance, running the `polybar mybar`) reads the configuration file for any given modules. A full example can be seen [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polybar#Sample_configuration). Custom or user defined modules are loaded by calling the relevant script file. For instance:

```
[module/test]
type = custom/script
exec = some/script/file
tail = true
```

Polybar accepts, at the very least, shell scripts and python scripts (and perhaps others, though I have not tested this). For the purposes of this question, I am concerned with the appropriateness of my shell script and **not** its interface with polybar (which currently works as expected; though as @EdMorton [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900817/check-whether-string-contains-emoji-in-posix-if-statement/76900818?noredirect=1#comment135568149_76900818), this may not be intended functionality, hence this question).

### Current code

The following is a minimal working example of my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

smile=#d1dadf;
sad=#ff5833;
angry=#1a88a4;
laugh=#daf7a6;

while true; do

    # get hour
    time=$(date +%_H -u);

    # set empty hour
    timeShow=TEST;

    # set empty emoji
    emoji=;

    if [ $time -ge 0 ] && [ $time -lt 6 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$smile}%{F-}
    elif [ $time -ge 6 ] && [ $time -lt 12 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$sad}%{F-}
    elif [ $time -ge 12 ] && [ $time -lt 18 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$angry}%{F-}
    elif [ $time -ge 18 ] && [ $time -ne 0 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$laugh}%{F-}
    fi

    if [[ "$emoji" =~ [] ]];
    then
        ((timeShow = time - 1))
    elif [[ "$emoji" =~ [] ]];
    then
        ((timeShow = time - 2))
    elif [[ "$emoji" =~ [] ]];
    then
        ((timeShow = time - 3))
    fi

    echo "$timeShow:$(date '+%M' -u) $emoji"
    
    sleep 1
done
```

### Explanation of inputs (and outputs)

Running the script as is requires no input (the output is calculated from within the script itself). Hence running the script is simply done via:

```
./script.sh
```

The output should (and does) return the formatted time, along with the emoji wrapped in colour format tags, as described above.

The program as it stands takes the current UTC hour from `date`. This value (stored in the variable `time`) is then modified and stored within `timeShow`. Assuming a particular range of hours (and hence `emoji`), the script then modifies `timeShow` by either subtracting 1, 2, or 3. The emoji are found in the string `emoji` by performing a regex operation to locate the character, which is wrapped by colour formatting.

### Expected output given hardcoded input

Changing the following:

```
 while true; do... done
```

To this:

```
for time in 8 12 22 0; do... done
```

In addition, the following lines should be changed to match below:

```
# get hour
#time=$(date +%_H -u);

# set default hour
timeShow=0
```

Should give the following as expected outputs, assuming the script is run on the hour.

Loop 1 (at 8 am) (offset of -1):

```
7:00 %{F#ff5833}%{F-}
```

Loop 2 (at 12 pm) (offset of -2):

```
10:00 %{F#1a88a4}%{F-}
```

Loop 3 (at 10 pm) (offset of -3):

```
19:00 %{F#daf7a6}%{F-}
```

Loop 4 (at 12 am) (offset of 0):

```
0:00 %{F#d1dadf}%{F-}
```

### Desired output

The script works as intended. As mentioned above, however, this may not be accidental. The purpose of this question is to understand whether the approach used is producing the correct output, or only *happens* to do so. The regex at present isolates the **character** by using the `[]`. For any glyph which may comprise 2 or more characters, `M-bM-^XM-^A$` for instance, isolating the emoji thusly, `[]` is potentially inaccurate as it would match the first corresponding character, leading to undesirable or unexpected behaviour. Further explanation of this problem is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900817/check-whether-string-contains-emoji-in-posix-if-statement/76900818#comment135568149_76900818).

Comment: Why use pattern matching at all? Why not just set an `offset` variable in the first `if/elif` block, then subtract that from `time`?

Comment: You don't need the `[]` around the emoji. `[]` is used to match any of a set of characters; if there's just one character, `=~ [char]` is the same as `=~ char`

Comment: @Barmar, unfortunately I am not very familiar with how to do this. As I understand it, I would keep the first `if elif fi` block, and set values into a variable there. Then instead of using regex to check as the expression in the next `if elif fi` block, I use this new variable and set all the string formatting there?

Comment: `let` itself is non-POSIX syntax bash supports only for backwards compatibility. Use either regular string assignments (`foo=$bar`) or POSIX arithmetic contexts (`foo=$(( bar ))`. For strings that aren't numeric in nature, neither `let` nor any other kind of arithmetic context is appropriate at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I will amend my local code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching `$emoji` with a regexp, set another variable when you're setting `emoji`, and use that when setting `timeShow`.

```
#!/bin/bash

smile=#d1dadf;
sad=#ff5833;
angry=#1a88a4;
laugh=#daf7a6;

while true; do

    # get hour
    time=$(date +%_H -u);

    # set empty hour
    timeShow=TEST;
    timeOffset=0

    # set empty emoji
    emoji=;

    if [ $time -ge 0 ] && [ $time -lt 6 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$smile}%{F-}
            timeOffset=3
    elif [ $time -ge 6 ] && [ $time -lt 12 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$sad}%{F-}
            timeOffset=1
    elif [ $time -ge 12 ] && [ $time -lt 18 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$angry}%{F-}
            timeOffset=2
    elif [ $time -ge 18 ] && [ $time -ne 0 ];
    then
            emoji=%{F$laugh}%{F-}
            timeOffset=3
    fi

    timeshow=$((time - timeOffset)

    echo "$timeShow:$(date '+%M' -u) $emoji"
    
    sleep 1 &
    wait
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant alternative solution; I could not see it at first when reading the comment but it is very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

emojis[3]=%{F#d1dadf}%{F-}
emojis[1]=%{F#ff5833}%{F-}
emojis[2]=%{F#1a88a4}%{F-}
emojis[0]=%{F#daf7a6}%{F-}

while true; do

    # get hour
    TZ=UTC printf -v hour '%(%k)T' -1

    if   (( hour == 0 )); then delta=0
    elif (( hour <  6 )); then delta=3
    elif (( hour < 12 )); then delta=1
    elif (( hour < 18 )); then delta=2
    else                       delta=0
    fi

    emoji="${emojis[$delta]}"
    hourShow=$(( hour - delta ))
    TZ=UTC printf -v min '%(%M)T' -1

    printf '%d:%02d %s\n' "$hourShow" "$min" "$emoji"

    sleep 1
done
```

Since you're using bash and arithmetic operations in the assignment contexts there's no reason not to also use them in comparisons, there's no point always testing the previous range end in an if-else, and no reason I can think of to use `sleep 1 &; wait` instead of just `sleep 1`.

Here it is tweaked to use the specific hour values the OP provided for testing, done at 2:58pm UTC:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

emojis[3]=%{F#d1dadf}%{F-}
emojis[1]=%{F#ff5833}%{F-}
emojis[2]=%{F#1a88a4}%{F-}
emojis[0]=%{F#daf7a6}%{F-}

#while true; do
for hour in 8 8 12 22 0; do

    # get hour
    #TZ=UTC printf -v hour '%(%k)T' -1

    if   (( hour == 0 )); then delta=0
    elif (( hour <  6 )); then delta=3
    elif (( hour < 12 )); then delta=1
    elif (( hour < 18 )); then delta=2
    else                       delta=0
    fi

    emoji="${emojis[$delta]}"
    hourShow=$(( hour - delta ))
    TZ=UTC printf -v min '%(%M)T' -1

    printf '%d:%02d %s\n' "$hourShow" "$min" "$emoji"

    sleep 1
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
7:58 %{F#ff5833}%{F-}
7:58 %{F#ff5833}%{F-}
10:58 %{F#1a88a4}%{F-}
22:58 %{F#daf7a6}%{F-}
0:58 %{F#daf7a6}%{F-}
```

You might want to change each `%d` to `%02d` in the printfs so you get 2-digits hour values, e.g. `07:58` instead of `7:58`.

Comment: If you're going to use one bashism (arrays), might think about using another (built-in time formatting). `printf -v hour '%(%H)T' -1` is a fair bit faster than spawning `date` as a subprocess.